# Clickable element of ListView with gridView inside (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I want to make listView element clickable.
When i add gridView inside listView then i cant click on listView element..

How to make listView element clickable when gridView is inside listView?
I try to set focusable, descendantFocusability, clickable...

**ProductsFragment.java**

```
package pl.pieczolap.ui.products;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import pl.globoox.pieczolap.R;
import pl.pieczolap.API.getProducts;
import pl.pieczolap.MyGridView;

public class ProductsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProductsViewModel StampViewModel;

    ArrayList<String> product_uid_shop = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> product_uid_product = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> product_name = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> product_info = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> product_stamps = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> product_clientStamps = new ArrayList();

    MyGridView gridView_stamps;
    ListView listView_products;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    Integer clientStamps;
    Integer needStamps;
    ImageView imageView_loadingData;

    TextView textView_winner;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StampViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProductsViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);

        // LOAD GIF LOADING IMAGE
        imageView_loadingData = root.findViewById(R.id.imageView_loadingData);
        Glide.with(root).load(R.drawable.loadingdots).placeholder(R.drawable.loadingdots).into(imageView_loadingData);

        listView_products = root.findViewById(R.id.listView_products);
        sharedPref = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pl.piecozlap", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Bundle arguments = this.getArguments();
        String uid_shop = arguments.getString("uid_shop", "none");

        // GET ALL STAMPS
        Response.Listener<String> responseListenerUserComments = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    int errorCode = jsonResponse.getInt("errorCode");

                    // CANT CONNECT TO DATABASE
                    if (errorCode == 1) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        builder.setMessage("Brak połączenia z bazą danych!").setNegativeButton("PONÓW", null).create().show();

                    }


                    // GET STAMP AND PRODUCT INFO
                    if (errorCode == 2) {

                        JSONArray products = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("products");
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = products.getJSONObject(i);
                            product_uid_shop.add(jsonObject.getString("uid_shop"));
                            product_uid_product.add(jsonObject.getString("uid_product"));
                            product_name.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            product_info.add(jsonObject.getString("info"));
                            product_stamps.add(jsonObject.getString("stamps"));
                            product_clientStamps.add(jsonObject.getString("clientStamps"));

                        }

                        // HIDE LOADING GIF
                        imageView_loadingData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        ProductsAdapter productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter();
                        listView_products.setAdapter(productsAdapter);


                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        getProducts getStamps = new getProducts(sharedPref.getString("uid_client", "none"), uid_shop, responseListenerUserComments);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(getStamps);


        return root;
    }


    // LISTVIEW CUSTOMADAPTER
    // LISTVIEW CUSTOMADAPTER
    // LISTVIEW CUSTOMADAPTER
    // LISTVIEW CUSTOMADAPTER
    public class ProductsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return product_uid_shop.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout_products, null);

            clientStamps = Integer.valueOf(product_clientStamps.get(position));
            needStamps = Integer.valueOf(product_stamps.get(position));

            TextView textView_product_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_product_name);
            TextView textView_product_info = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_product_info);
            textView_product_name.setText(String.valueOf(clientStamps));
            textView_product_info.setText(product_info.get(position));

            // WINNER TEXTVIEW
            TextView textView_winner = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_winner);
            if (clientStamps == needStamps) {
                textView_winner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                textView_winner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }


            // -------------------- //
            //    CLICK ON SHOP     //
            // -------------------- //
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.d("TAGA", "sasdadsa");

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                            .setTitle("Delete entry")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // Continue with delete operation
                                }
                            })

                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();
                }
            });


            gridView_stamps = convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridView_stamps);
            StampsAdapter stampAdapter = new StampsAdapter();
            gridView_stamps.setAdapter(stampAdapter);
            gridView_stamps.setClickable(false);


            return convertView;
        }

    }


    // STAMP GRIDVIEW
    // STAMP GRIDVIEW
    // STAMP GRIDVIEW
    // STAMP GRIDVIEW
    public class StampsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return needStamps;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout_onestamp, null);

            if (position < clientStamps) {
                final ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgageView_onestamp);
                Picasso.get().load("http://pieczolap.pl/admin/shops/999/stamp.jpg").into(imageView);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }


}
```

**customlayout_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customlayout_shops_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/customlayout_shops_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_product_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_product_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_product_name"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <pl.pieczolap.MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView_stamps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relativeLayout"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_winner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:rotation="-6"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Zebrano wszystkie!"
        android:textSize="30dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_addShop" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_loadingData"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```